# Related object, non-lookup validation rule?

Tags: apex, trigger

our sales team is using a custom object `Exception_Tracking__c` to keep track of various exceptions on the `Opportunity` before it becomes a deal.  There's a lookup to Opportunity in the `Exception_Tracking__c` object, but not an `Exception_Tracking__c` lookup on the `Opportunity` (just a related list).

A really pointless field that Sales just ***has*** to have is `Opportunity.Exception_NA__c` (boolean).

If there aren't any Exceptions for a specific Opportunity, they'll mark that as TRUE.  However, they also want validation in place to prevent a user from marking the field as TRUE if there are any related `Exception_Tracking__c` records.  Trying to figure out how to do this.

My understanding is that standard validation won't work and I would need to use Apex.  I'm thinking I would need to do a Map of some kind, but just don't know how to tie it all together.  My failed attempt:

```
trigger OpportunityExceptionTrigger on Opportunity (before insert, before update) {
    
    
    
    Map<Id,Exception_Tracking__c> exceptionRelatedFields=new Map<Id,Exception_Tracking__c>(
                [Select Opportunity__r.Id 
                  from Exception_Tracking__c 
                  where Opportunity__c IN:Trigger.New]);
    
    For(Opportunity opp : trigger.new){
        If(opp.Exception_NA__c == TRUE && exceptionRelatedFields.get(opp.Id) != null){
            opp.addError('Because there are Exception Tracking records submitted for this Opportunity, the Exception NA field cannot be marked as true');
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: why don't you just store an exception tracking count on the opportunity? seems strange that someone at one point in time will set a field value, which will become invalid if someone then adds an exception tracking record to it

Answer (score 1):

What you have right now seems pretty close to me.

The only things of note are:

- `<something> == true` can always be reduced to simply `<something>` (mostly a code style thing, shouldn't cause any problems)
- Records do not have Ids in a `before insert` context, and it's thus impossible to have related records `before insert`

So remove the `before insert` from the contexts that your trigger runs in, and things should work. You'll probably want to have a way to automatically uncheck `Exception_NA__c` if any exception tracking records are related to a given opportunity, but that's out of scope for this question. A trigger on `Exception_Tracking__c` should do the trick, and honestly, you should consider making `Exception_NA__c` read-only and have it be automatically managed though code (so that you can do away with your trigger on Opportunity and prevent Sales from trying to game the system). Using the DLRS (Declarative Lookup Rollup Summary) tool from Andrew Fawcett is an easy way to handle simple things like this (count the child records, make a checkbox formula field that is checked only when the count is 0).

If you do decide to continue on your own, you should be using a trigger framework instead of having logic inside of your triggers (and don't forget, best practice is 1 trigger for any given SObject).

Comment: Hmm, unfortunately it's not working as expected.  I thought if I add:
if(opp.exception_na__c == true && exceptionRelatedFields.get(opp.Id).Opportunity__c != null), that would fix it but now I'm getting a null pointer exception.

Answer (score -1):

Got this figured out by utilizing the size of the map:

```
trigger OpportunityExceptionTrigger on Opportunity (before update) {
     
    Map<Id,Exception_Tracking__c> exceptionRelatedFields=new Map<Id,Exception_Tracking__c>([Select Id, Opportunity__c from Exception_Tracking__c where Opportunity__c IN:Trigger.New]);
    system.debug(exceptionrelatedfields.size());
    
    For(Opportunity opp : trigger.new){
        If(opp.Exception_NA__c == TRUE && exceptionRelatedFields.size() > 0){
            opp.addError('Because there are Exception Tracking records submitted for this Opportunity, the Exception NA field cannot be marked as true');
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This'll give you false positives if you do a DML update on two or more opps with at least one opp that has children and at least one that does not. You really do need to check for the existence of child records for each opp.

Comment: Or rather, a false positive when you have 1 opp with Exception_NA__c checked and 0 children, and 1 opp with Exception_NA__c not checked and with 1+ children.